# How to setup python Pusher to send messages server to server?

Tags: python, pusher

I am trying to setup Pusher to send messages from server to server.  I do not need a client setup.  I am trying to make the one server aware the other server is finished doing a particular task.  Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I work for Pusher. Have you tried using [our server libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/libraries)? Some platforms have both a client (subscription) and server (publishing) library so you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: I got that far, i cannot get passed an issue:  ImportError: No module named urllib.parse

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Python you're using, and which library and version you're using (a link to it would be great)?